# strsplit by a particular character, provied that character should not be followed by a particular character

Tags: r, pattern-matching, strsplit

I want to split the string whenever it encounters "a", provided "a" should not be followed by "b"

```
string <- "abcgualoo87ahhabta"
```

I should get output as

```
string <- [1]abcgua
[2]loo87a
[3]hhabta
```

Comment: Look for a regex tutorial that explains negative lookahead.

Comment: Why is the last `a` splitted? Doesn't compute with the 1-3 elements, in which the splitting `a` is the last character (and not the first). Try `strsplit(string,"(?<=a)(?!b)",perl=TRUE)` and listen to the @Roland's advice.

Comment: @nicola, I added your line in my answer to make it more visible, if you want to post it as separate answer, let me no so I can delete your line (or feel free to edit my A to remove the last part)

Comment: @CathG No problem at all, keep the line in your answer.

Comment: @nicola i corrected the last split on a

Answer (score 6):

You can split your string with the pattern "a not followed by b" with the regex `a(?=[^b])` in `strsplit`:

```
split_str <- strsplit("abcgualoo87ahhabta", "a(?=[^b])", perl=TRUE)[[1]]
split_str
#[1] "abcgu"  "loo87"  "hhabta"
```

*explanation of the split pattern:* a lookahead (`(?=)`) is used with, as "look-ahead" pattern, anything except a b (`[^b]`) (the ^ sign indicates the negation). In order for the lookahead to work (be interpreted), we need to set parameter `perl` to `TURE`

Then you can add the removed "a" at the end of the splitted part, except last:

```
split_str <- paste0(c(rep("a", length(split_str)-1), ""))
#[1] "abcgua" "loo87a" "hhabta"
```

***A nice one-step alternative provided by @nicola in the comments:***

```
split_str <- strsplit("abcgualoo87ahhabta","(?<=a)(?!b)", perl=TRUE)[[1]]
#[1] "abcgua" "loo87a" "hhabta"
```

Comment: I would really encourage you to use `TRUE` and `FALSE` instead of `T` and `F`.

Comment: @CathG it would be great if you can explain the meaning of a(?=[^b]) and also if i add another condition that split string if we get "a" or "g" not followed by "b". how to precced in such scenario

Comment: @DHWANIDHOLAKIA I edited with an explanation, let me know if it's ok or if you'd like more details

Comment: @CathG The above explanation was very informative. For the next condition wherein i want to split the string if there is "a|g" not followed by  "b". I changed the above code to **strsplit("abcgualoo87ahhabta", "a|g(?=[^b])", perl=TRUE)[[1]]** however i got very different results [1] ""      "bc"    "u"     "loo87" "hh"    "bt"

Comment: @DHWANIDHOLAKIA you need to put `(a|g)` in brackets, else your asking a or (g not followed by b) so it splits at every a

Comment: @CathG it worked after putting the brackets. But in case when there was only one condition to split we can add "a" to the beginning as shown in your second statement   **strsplit("abcgualoo87ahhabta", "a|g(?=[^b])", perl=TRUE)[[1]]** but this case it would be complicated as we dont know where to put "a" or "g"

Comment: @CathG i ran the changed condition using your second one line answer and it workd .

Comment: @CathG Can you tell me the difference when to put parenthesis () and when [ ]  in such situations

Comment: @DHWANIDHOLAKIA in regex [ and ( have not the same meaning (you can have a look at `?regex` to learn more) but actually `[ag](?=[^b])` instead of `(a|g)(?=[^b])` works too

Answer (score 2):

```
string <- "abcgualoo87ahhabta"
unlist(strsplit(gsub("a([^b])", "a \\1", string), split=" "))
# [1] "abcgua" "loo87a" "hhabta"
```